# Is there a more ideal way to query data from another database using SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure which gets data from another database on the same server.

I will not be hard-coding which database to use, instead this will be configurable. Is this possible without dynamic sql?

The best solution I could come up with so far is to first run a stored procedure which uses dynamic sql to generate a bunch of views. I can then select data from these views to avoid using dynamic SQL for everything.

Example:

```
DECLARE 
    @databaseName nvarchar(max),
    @sql          nvarchar(max)

-- Get this value from a configuration table
SET @databaseName = 'TestDatabase'

IF EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM dbo.SysObjects WHERE [Name] = 'TestView')
    DROP VIEW dbo.TestView

SET @sql = 'CREATE VIEW dbo.TestView AS SELECT * FROM ' + @databaseName +'.dbo.TestTable'

EXEC (@sql)

--I can now select from TestView using regular query.
```

I'm guessing that I'm going about this the wrong way. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why, if the code above works, do you want to avoid it? It may not be your thing at all, but you've heard of SSIS?

Comment: Tobiasopdenbrouw, Is there a way I could get an SSIS package to use a different database based on a value in a table?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

[OPENQUERY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx) or [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for this. Both those options are very interesting, however they still rely on building a sql string.

Comment: Then do please tell us why you're opposed to that.

Comment: Bugs are more easily introduced and harder to debug with dynamic SQL. I could write a stored proc with random nonsense in a SQL string, and I won't know about the problem until I tried to run it.